# PrintCapabilities not returning Duplex for enabled printer

Tags: wpf, vb.net, printing

I have an HP 6500 printer that will print in Duplex when set appropriately.

I'm working on a program to print automatically to other printers, but I notice a problem with the PrintCapabilities for this printer - it does not contain JobDuplexAllDocumentsContiguously - the Duplex options.

The method is below. I can't post the results because they are too long.  Does anyone know why this does not work as expected? I would like to confirm that a printer can print Duplex before I send it a job, but how?

Rick

Here is how I get the PrintCapabilites:

```
  Dim pq As Printing.PrintQueue = Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue
            ' get a stored printticket that has Duplex = TwoSidedShortEdge
            Dim ps As RG.Data.Program_Setting = RG.Data.Program_Setting.GetObject(Environment.MachineName)
            Dim cs As RG.Data.Computer_Setting = ps.value_object_cast
            Dim pt As Printing.PrintTicket = cs.print_ticket_document
            'confirm that duplex is set
            MsgBox(pt.Duplexing.ToString)
            Dim ms = pq.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml(pt)
            ms.Position = 0
            Using fs = RG.Utilities.GetTempFileStream(".xml")
                fs.Write(ms.ToArray, 0, ms.Length - 1)
                fs.Close()
            End Using
```

I have also tried pq.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml() and get the same results:

Comment: I forgot to mention that the driver is up to date.

Comment: If you look at the print driver setting does it say it has the duplexing accessory installed ?

Comment: Yes, in Printer Properties, Device Settings, Advanced Features it shows that Duplex is installed